# Capybara will not load assets when I visit the same page twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

Using 1.1.2,

```
describe 'something', :javascript => true, :selenium => true  do
  before do
    visit root_path 
  end

  it 'works' do
    ...
  end

  it 'doesnt work' do
    ...
  end
end
```

I'm using handlebars to render some JS templates in my app but, since updating to Rails 3.1, my JS is not being loaded when root_path is visited the second time to run the 'doesnt work' spec. Is there something I am missing here? I know that Capybara had some updates made to it for the Asset Pipeline but are these fixes in 1.1.2? If not, could someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong to get this behavior?